# Как текстурировать 3д модель в Three.Js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Столкнулся с проблемой текстурирования моделей. Если текстурировать обычные объекты то проблем нет, но если модели загруженные из вне то не получается. В чём может быть проблема?

```
//если текстурировать obj модель не работает
let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
let texture = loader.load('texture.png');
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
     map: texture
});
this.objLoader.load('model.obj', (model) => {
    let modelTextured = new THREE.Mesh(model,material)
    scene.add(modelTextured);
});
```

```
//если текстурировать примитивные объекты то работает
    let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    let texture = loader.load('texture.png');
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: texture
    });
    let geomentry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10);
    let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geomentry,material);
    scene.add(cube);
```

Comment: а этот obj вообще отображается ?

Comment: gltf Loader подключен ?

Comment: да все модели подгружаются все модули тоже подключены проблема именно с текстурированием

Comment: тогда х.з извените

Comment: у вас получалось текстурировать модели таким образом?

Comment: можете на [их форуме типа SO](https://discourse.threejs.org/top/weekly) спросить

Comment: Тред на форуме, если кому интересно: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-texture-a-3d-model-in-three-js/25035

Comment: это мой вопрос) но спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того что бы модель имела текстуру вам нужно воспользоваться любым 3д редактором. Я использовал Blender. В Blender я корректно развернул модель и наложил на её uv-map текстуру моей модели. После этого я экспортировал модель в формате  glb.

Далее в Three.js вы загружаете вашу  glb модель в ваш проект и добавляете в сцену и всё прекрасно работает

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

const loader  = new GLTFLoader(),

this.loader.load( 'model.glb',  ( gltf )=> {
     scene.add( gltf.scene );
}
```